# How to control Visibility of ComboBox based on radio button is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a quick WPF question in regards to the visibility of my `ComboBox` with respects to whether or not a button is checked or not. The goal is that when the user checks the radio button: 'btnCurrent', the `ComboBox`: `cboHistorySequence` will be hidden, and when the button 'btnHistory' is checked, it will appear.

**VIEW: Here we have the radio button 'btnCurrent' and 'btnHistory', as well as combobox cboHistorySequence.**

```
 <RadioButton x:Name="btnCurrent" IsChecked="{Binding IsCurrentSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Current" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>

 <RadioButton x:Name="btnHistory" IsChecked="{Binding IsHistorySelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="History" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsHistorySelected, Converter={StaticResource EnabledConverter} }">
     <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="80">History Seq:</TextBlock>
     <ComboBox x:Name="cboHistorySequence" Margin="16,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=HistorySequence, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
         <ComboBoxItem>First</ComboBoxItem>
         <ComboBoxItem>Last</ComboBoxItem>
     </ComboBox>
 </StackPanel>
```

**What I have tried**

My initial thought was to use something along the lines of this and bind it over to the view-model, but I have not been successful. What are yall's recommendations?

```
Visibility="{Binding IsShowComboBox, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to bind to the property of another element in your application you should use [`Binding.ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.elementname) Property and `Path`, something like this:

```
<ComboBoxItem>Last</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  ElementName=btnCurrent, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

Comment: it also usefull to place a "default" setter (`<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />`) in your style, right after `<Style ...>` and before `<Style.Triggers>`